# How to disable memojis on contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'd like to remove memojis support on my contenteditable element because it completely destroys my design. I still want to keep standard emoji's.

Can you please advise?

Comment: You can validate / remove them by using a [regex](https://www.regextester.com/106421). What do you mean by `standard emoji's`?

Comment: I mean the memojis stickers on iOS (when you open the emojis keyboard).  standard emojis are the known emojis keyboard.

Comment: I'm not familiar with them (and don't have an iphone to check) sorry.